# why won't fortran read a row and write to file?

Tags: fortran, row

I am trying to read a file put each row into a variable called row, and from that row I take the values in certain locations and put it into another variable. Which should then write to the file. How do you do that?

```
program read_block
implicit none
real :: x,y
integer :: ios
character(len=100) :: row

open(unit=101, file='block2trimmed.gro',action='read',status='old')
open(unit=102, file='readoutput.gro', action='write',status='new')
do
read(101, '(i5,2a5,i5,3f8.3,3f8.4)',iostat=ios) row
if (ios /= 0) exit
read(row(21:28),*) x
read(row(29:36),*) y


write(102,*) x , y
end do
close(101)
close(102)
end program read_block
```

Comment: You presumably get an error from the compiler or when running. Please show that. I see, however, that you are trying to read in to the character `row` with `i5`: that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

OP seems to be mixing up two different approaches to reading the file, either of which would work, but not both at the same time.

One could either read an entire line of text (into the `row` variable) then pick it apart into the separate data fields (using `read(row(21:28),*) x` and similar).  Or one could just read the separate fields directly into variables as required, using the format to tell the code where to find the individual items on each line.  For a `.gro` file, go with the latter approach.  The lines in the file are carefully laid out in the way specified in the format.

This line

```
read(101, '(i5,2a5,i5,3f8.3,3f8.4)',iostat=ios) row
```

carefully tells the compiler to read

- an integer in a 5-character-wide field;
- two strings, each of 5 characters;
- another integer in a 5-character-wide field;
- 3 real numbers, from an 8-character field, with 3 digits after the decimal place; and
- 3 real numbers, from an 8-character field, with 4 digits after the decimal place;

and then tells it to stuff them all into a 100-character string called `row`.  It's kind of crazee, and even crazier when it then tries to parse the string back into the separate elements.  Throw away that line and replace it with something like:

```
read(101, '(i5,2a5,i5,3f8.3,3f8.4)',iostat=ios) int1, str1, str2, int2, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6
```

For this to work you'll have to declare all those variables, and you might want to give them more meaningful names.  And if you are only interested in some of the variables, ignore the other ones.

It would be possible to read the line into the string `row` and then to pick it apart, but it would take another 10 lines of code to achieve what that one line does, and dispenses with `row` altogether.  A Gromos `.gro` file is designed for easy reading so read it easily.

As for writing them out, the right way to do that depends on what you want to do next with the data but the line

```
write(102,*) int1, str1, str2, int2, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6
```

is quick and easy, though it may not be what you need.